# Creating Class Methods

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure why I'm receiving errors when I try to find an instance using the class method which I've defined.

bank_account.rb

```
class BankAccount 
    attr_reader :balance

    def self.create_for(first_name, last_name)
        @accounts ||= []
        @accounts << BankAccount.new(first_name, last_name) 
    end

    def self.find_for(first_name, last_name)
        @accounts.find{|account| account.full_name == "#{first_name} #{last_name}"}
    end

    def initialize(first_name, last_name)
        @balance = 0
        @first_name = first_name
        @last_name = last_name
    end

    def full_name 
        "#{first_name} #{@last_name}"
    end

    def deposit(amount)
        @balance += amount 
    end

    def withdraw(amount)
        @balance -= amount 
    end

end
```

In irb, I've created two bank accounts using create_for class method.

```
$BankAccount.create_for("Brad", "Pitt")
$BankAccount.create_for("Angelina", "Jolie")
```

When I tried to find the instance,

```
$BankAccount.find_for("Angelina", "Joile")
```

I received this error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `first_name' for #<BankAccount:0x007fb914a47700>
```

I'm not sure why it says that the 'first_name' is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The below part

```
def full_name 
   "#{first_name} #{@last_name}" # <~~ here you missed @ symbol before first_name
end
```

needs to be

```
def full_name 
   "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
end
```

**Full code:**

```
class BankAccount 
    attr_reader :balance

    def self.create_for(first_name, last_name)
        @accounts ||= []
        @accounts << BankAccount.new(first_name, last_name) 
    end

    def self.find_for(first_name, last_name)
        @accounts.find{|account| account.full_name == "#{first_name} #{last_name}"}
    end

    def initialize(first_name, last_name)
        @balance = 0
        @first_name = first_name
        @last_name = last_name
    end

    def full_name 
        "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
    end

    def deposit(amount)
        @balance += amount 
    end

    def withdraw(amount)
        @balance -= amount 
    end
    def self.account_holders;@accounts;end

end
BankAccount.create_for("Brad", "Pitt")
BankAccount.create_for("Angelina", "Jolie")
BankAccount.find_for("Angelina", "Jolie")
# => #<BankAccount:0x99de7d0
#     @balance=0,
#     @first_name="Angelina",
#     @last_name="Jolie">

BankAccount.account_holders
# => [#<BankAccount:0x99de8d4
#      @balance=0,
#      @first_name="Brad",
#      @last_name="Pitt">,
#     #<BankAccount:0x99de7d0
#      @balance=0,
#      @first_name="Angelina",
#      @last_name="Jolie">]
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have checked more carefully! I'll accept the answer in 6 min

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can display all the objects I've created for BankAccount? Do I need to create a method for this? I tried BankAccount.all but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: @wag0325 Just add a method like `def self.account_holders;@accounts;end`. Then call it as `BankAccount.account_holders`. That's it.